# How to retrieve more than 100000 rows from Redshift using R and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, amazon-redshift, rpostgresql

I'm analyzing data from a Redshift database, working in R using a connection per dplyr - which works:

```
my_db<-src_postgres(host='my-cluster-blahblah.redshift.amazonaws.com', port='5439', dbname='dev',user='me', password='mypw')
mytable <- tbl(my_db, "mytable")

viewstation<-mytable %>%
    filter(stationname=="something")
```

When I try to turn that output into a data frame, so:

```
thisdata<-data.frame(viewstation)
```

I get the error message, 
Warning message:

```
Only first 100,000 results retrieved. Use n = -1 to retrieve all.
```

Where am I supposed to set n?

Comment: Note, I would indeed like to subset to fewer than 100000 points, but I cant do that: thisdata<-sample_n(viewstation,100000) generates the error, "Error: Don't know how to sample from objects of class tbl_postgres"

Comment: A better practice is to do the subset using the WHERE clause in your SELECT query to Redshift. It will prevent the unnecessary transfer of the data over the network and fill up the memory of your machine.

Comment: but i want all that data :)  I want all those hundreds of thousands of points.  A random select to bring the number down is an OK second best merely.  and if possible I'd rather stay within dplyr - so so easy for the use cases where it works....

Comment: i know that you can set n in a query managed from rpostgresql directly - it is a parameter to "fetch" command.  But how from dplyr can I get to that?

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using

```
thisdata<-data.frame(viewstation)
```

use

```
thisdata <- collect(viewstation)
```

collect() will pull all the data from the database back into R. As mentioned in the DPLYR::databases vignette:

> When working with databases, dplyr tries to be as lazy as possible. It’s lazy in two ways:
>
> It never pulls data back to R unless you explicitly ask for it.
>
> It delays doing any work until the last possible minute, collecting together everything you want to do then sending that to the database in one step.

Comment: ooo @phiver i think it works.  followed by `thisdata_df<-data.frame(thisdata)`

Answer (score 0):

#### For those who are still using dplyr 0.5 (like me).

The parameter `n` is part of the `collect` function.

```
my_db<-src_postgres(host='my-cluster-blahblah.redshift.amazonaws.com', port='5439', dbname='dev',user='me', password='mypw')
mytable <- tbl(my_db, "mytable") %>% collect(n = Inf)
```

This will get you **more than 100.000 rows**.